# Should you use the equals method or compare the event type IDs for EventType in Esper?

Tags: java, esper

I am trying to check if two of Esper's `EventType` objects are equal. By equal I mean that they are the same event types with the same properties.

I was wondering what is the best way to do it. Is it safe to use the equals method, like this:

```
eventType.equals(otherEventType)
```

As `EventType` is an interface, I cannot be sure that all the implementing classes will override the equals method. Because of this I assume the above code is not a good idea.

The other option that I can think of is to compare the event type IDs, like this:

```
eventType.getEventTypeId() == eventType.getEventTypeId()
```

However, I am not sure how these IDs are assigned. Will this give me what I am looking for, or is there better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event type id is a unique id per type thus not suitable.
"Equals" is also not suitable.
Since it depends on application semantics whether a type is the same or not you need to write your own compare.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am just a bit unsure what you mean by 'a unique id per type.' Does this mean that if I get an `EventType` from an `EPStatement`, when I create the statement, and then get the other `EventType` from an `EventBean`, when that same statement outputs, they will have different event type IDs?